# links in display:block are not correctly in div with position:absolute

Tags: css, html

I don't understand why my links are not the .pushMenu divs (left and right),

html:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="pushMenu" id="left">
        <a href="" title=""><p>l</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="pushMenu" id="right">
        <a href="" title=""><p>r</p></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="myTitle">title</span>
        <span class="myBy">(by me)</span>
    </div>
```

css:

```
header {
    text-align: center !important;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
header div.pushMenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
header div.pushMenu#left {left: 10px;}
header div.pushMenu#right {right: 10px;}
header div.pushMenu a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
}
```

see in action: http://jsfiddle.net/GDQdU/4/

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `line-height` specified for the `header` is being rendered by the child elements also. Check below to correct this.

Remove the `p` tag from the `a` tag and the html will be like this `<a href="" title="">r</a>`
and add `line-height:30px` to the `a` tag.

```
header div.pushMenu a{
  line-height:30px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/PQ8Ww/)**

**OR**

If you want the p tag to be there then make the following css changes

```
header div.pushMenu p{
  margin:0;
  line-height:30px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/PQ8Ww/1/)**